# My first chrome extension / chrome.tabs.executeScript problem

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, permissions

Im trying to build my first chrome extension and practise my skills.

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Test",
    "description": "Its a test",
    "version": "1.0",
    "action": {
        "default_icon": {                // optional
          "16": "15.jpg",     // optional
          "24": "15.jpg",     // optional
          "32": "15.jpg"      // optional
        },
        "default_popup": "popup.html"    // optional
      },  
      "host_permissions": [
        "*://*/*"
      ],
      "permissions": [
        "tabs"
      ]
}
```

**popup.js**

```
    
        function scheduleClick () {
            //chrome.tabs.executeScript({ code: 'console.log(document.getElementById("search_button"))' });
            document.getElementById("contentWrapper").innerHTML = "Click on " + buttonIDInput.value + " scheduled in " + delayInput.value + " seconds";
            var codeString = 'var button = document.getElementById("' + buttonIDInput.value + '"); setTimeout( function() { button.click(); }, ' +  delayInput.value * 1000 + ');'
            console.log(codeString)
            chrome.tabs.executeScript({ code: 'console.log(document.getElementById("Click on ' + buttonIDInput.value + ' scheduled in ' + delayInput.value + ' seconds"))' });
            chrome.tabs.executeScript({ code: codeString});
        };
        
        buttonIDInput = document.getElementById("clickID");
        //buttonIDInput = "search_button"
        delayInput = document.getElementById("delay");
    
        scheduleButton = document.getElementById("schedule");
        scheduleButton.addEventListener('click', scheduleClick, true);
    };
    
    
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', initialise, false);
```

**but here is the problem**

`Uncaught TypeError: chrome.tabs.executeScript is not a function`

I chekced lots of forums but i didnt figure out the problem , any tips ?